# Why is linear interpolation called lerp?

Tags: mathematics, programming

In the field of computer graphics, linear interpolation is called 'lerp'. This is very widely used.

I'm curious about why it is called so. I know it is listed in the Jargon file. The file says it is quasi-acronym of linear interpolation but why are L, E, R, and P chosen? In the first place, is it **l**in**e**a**r** inter**p**olation? or **l**inear int**erp**olation? or other?

I want to know exact origin.

Multiposting: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/71189

Comment: You have searched online and have found an acronymic explanation based on **L**inear Int**erp**olation. What more can be said?

Comment: As I commented in @Greybeard 's post, I don't think **l**inear int**erp**olation is logical, as well as other three patterns.

Comment: It's nerdism.  It doesn't need to follow any "rules".

Answer (score 5):

> is it ***l***inear int***erp***olation?

Yes.

> IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON IMAGE PROCESSING, VOL. 13, NO. 5, MAY 2004: “Linear Interpolation Revitalized” Thierry Blu, Member, IEEE, Philippe Thévenaz, Member, IEEE, and Michael Unser, Fellow, IEEE
>
> *The dotted lines indicate the L<sup>2</sup> interpolation error:*

It is clear that

**Linear Interpolation** reduces to **L-Interpolation**, which reduces to **L Interp**, which reduces to **Lerp**.

In contrast, **l**in**e**a**r** inter**p**olation is entirely illogical and seems to be a selection of random, emphasised and unemphasised letters.

Comment: I regret to point out that a question is not an answer.

Comment: I have added to my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think interpolation -> erp is also illogical. Finally mid part is taken and it's not seems essential part. Can you present other terms which is shorten into mid part in the same way?

Comment: @v..snow *I think interpolation -> erp is also illogical.* I'm not sure how you can think that when "Linear" reduces to an intial "L".

Comment: *Lint* was already taken.

Comment: @Greybeard Oxford dictionary says that acronym is a word formed from the **first letters** of the words. I can present many and many abbreviations which use first letters. English is en, Unites State is US, Language is lang. I typed (at)Grey to mention you now; not (at)eybe.

Comment: @v..snow As neither of your proposed derivations for "lerp" present an acronym, and as I have not mentioned "acronym", the mention of "acronym" seems to be irrelevant. An "acronym" is an abbreviation formed from the initial letters of other words and pronounced as a word (e.g. ASCII, NASA ). "@" is a punctuation symbol.

Comment: @Greybeard You asked why I accept initial letter of Linear, and I listed why. When I try to input user name, stack exchange completes from first letters. Regardless either it is acronym or not, first letters are nice to present a word. We and website can associate original word. That's why I think L of Liner if logical but erp of interpolation is not, or that's why I want more information to understand your answer, like other cases.